# Replicate MySQL yearweek function in postgres

Tags: mysql, postgresql, date, week-number

Converting a project from using MySQL to postgres and cannot figure out how to replicate MySQL's yearweek function.

For example, the following in MySQL:

```
select CAST(yearweek(user.created_at) AS CHAR CHARACTER SET utf8) as yrwk, user.created_at
```

returns:

```
"201452"    "2014-12-31 00:00:00"   "1"
"201601"    "2016-01-05 00:00:00"   "60"
"201601"    "2016-01-09 00:00:00"   "47"
"201623"    "2016-06-08 14:40:37"   "69"
```

How can I get the same result using postgres? I've tried using the EXTRACT function for both YEAR and WEEK and then concatenating them but postgres will return a 53 sometimes for dates at the beginning of the year, which throws everything out of whack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the function [`TO_CHAR`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html) with the appropriate format string.

To replicate the behaviour of YEARDATE exactly, the date has to be truncated to the start of the containing week.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(DATE_TRUNC('week', NOW()), 'YYYYWW')
-- outputs:
201826
```

and, using your example dates:

```
WITH dates(dt) AS (
VALUES 
('2014-12-31 00:00:00'::timestamp),
('2016-01-05 00:00:00'::timestamp),
('2016-01-09 00:00:00'::timestamp),
('2016-06-08 14:40:37'::timestamp)
)
SELECT dt, TO_CHAR(DATE_TRUNC('week', dt), 'YYYYWW') yrwk
FROM dates;
-- outputs:
         dt          |  yrwk
---------------------+--------
 2014-12-31 00:00:00 | 201452
 2016-01-05 00:00:00 | 201601
 2016-01-09 00:00:00 | 201601
 2016-06-08 14:40:37 | 201623
```